# Calculate the quotient graph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

My question is about parts c) and d) of this question:

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an oriented graph. For every pair of vertices $u,v \in V$, we write $u \leftrightarrow v $ iff there exists a path from $u$ to $v$ and a path from $v$ to $u$.

[image: graph]

In a) I was asked to show that it is an equivalence relation. So I went on and explained reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.

In b) I was asked to show the 'strongly connected' classes that have the relation $ \leftrightarrow $.

I have that $\{a,b\}$ and $\{f,h\}$ are strongly connected.... is  this ok **?**

Now in c). Let $P$ be a partition $P = \{V_1,V_2,...,V_k\}$ of the set of vertices $V$ of a graph $G$. We define the **quotient graph** as the graph $H$ of which the set of vertices is $P$ such that there exists an arc from $V_i$ to $V_j$ if $i \ne j $ and there exists an arc in $G$ from a vertex of $V_i$ to a vertex of $V_j$.

Calculate the quotient graph from the picture, for the partition given by the equivalence relation $\leftrightarrow$

I can't even understand it. Sorry if it's not clear, I have trouble translating it.

Where do I start with c)?

Also in d) I am asked to show that every quotient graph is acyclic...

Comment: You are being asked to draw a new graph with one vertex for each set of equivalent vertices. You are then asked to prove that any graph obtained this way will not have any closed loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer for b) is correct but incomplete. Note that a path can contain many edges.

$\leftrightarrow$ partitions the graph into the following sets: $\{a,b\}$, $\{c\}$ and $\{d,e,f,g,h\}$.
Two vertices of the graph are 'strongly connected' iff they are in the same set of this partition.

Your quotient graph will thus have $3$ vertices, given by $\{a,b\}$, $\{c\}$ and $\{d,e,f,g,h\}$. Can you figure out the edges between them?

Comment: Why is c in the partitions sets , so I have a-c-e ?

Comment: No, you have: $a\leftrightarrow b$ and $d\leftrightarrow e\leftrightarrow f\leftrightarrow g\leftrightarrow h$. If $x\leftrightarrow c$, then $x=c$ because the set of the partition containing $c$ is $\{c\}$.